# bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set up a bottom navigation in my app but after adding bottomNavigation, it doesn't work. When I test, I found below code doesn't work, which means no print even "abc" after running the app. The bottomNavigtionView is not null at this time.

I set a binding in MainActivity.

```
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        replaceFragment(new LibraryFragment());
        binding.bottomNavigationView.setBackground(null);
```

```
 binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener( item ->{
            System.out.println("abc");
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    System.out.println("xxx");
                    replaceFragment(new HomeFragment());
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_summary:
                    System.out.println("yyy");
                    replaceFragment(new LibraryFragment());
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_notifications:
                    System.out.println("zzz");
                    replaceFragment(new TestFragment());
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        });
```

```
    private  void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

My dependency looks like:

```
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1..0'
   implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0'
   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
   implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
   implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
   implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
   implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
   implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
   implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

Here is Activity_Main XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    tools:context=".features.mainscreen.MainActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="850dp" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/main_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is LibraryFragmeng XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LibraryFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="HelloB"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

I don't see any error when I run the code. When the app is open, it can only show "LibraryFragment".

Can anyone advise?

Thanks!

Comment: You should post the other relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Please share also activity related xml